# Missing page numbers in the indicies of Doxygen generated PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.5 and I have an issue with the generated indicies (Module Index, Data Structure Index, File Index etc.).
When I generate the PDF documentation with Doxygen extra indicies chapters "Module Index", "Data Structure Index" and "File Index" are generated. Unfortunately the page numbers in that indicies are not generated correctly, so that a "??" is shown instead of the page number, similar like this:

> ## Chapter 5
>
> ### File Index
>
> #### 5.1 File List
>
> Here is a list of all files with brief descriptions:
> bar.c  Doxygen C-file Example . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ??
> bar.h . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ??
> foo.c Doxygen C-file Example . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  ??
> foo.h Doxygen H-file Example . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  ??

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Latex needs multiple passes to resolve the page numbers, so you may need to run latex again. Note that the Makefile that doxygen generates in the latex output directory should run latex as often as is needed to get everything resolved.

Comment: Just a quick note for future reference (which is probably just for me): When I just run make inside of the latex folder I face the same problem; pdf2latex refman.tex works fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to workaround this issue. It seems to be a bug in Doxygen.
Just set the tag `CREATE_SUBDIRS` in the doxyfile to `NO`.

Comment: I have the same issue for two C headers, but this still didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try running with pdflatex command, it should generate it fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using MiKTeX / pdflatex: I execute `pdflatex refman` via command line in the folder `latex/output/doxygen`. After two using the command finally managed to get the page number :3

Screenshot before
[image: Screenshot Before]

Screenshot afterwards:
[image: Screenshot After generete pdflatex 2x]

if you try still can't. try installing all the Requirement files

- Ghostscript
- HTML Help Workshop and Documentation
- GraphViz
- MikTex (LaTeX)
- TexMaker – LaTeX Editor

Comment: Please see the comment form doxygen with the original post. It is not advised to run pdflatex directly and when using citations you will run in problems again, in the Makefile / make.bat this problem is handled.